# How can I insert a new Event for non primary Calendar? Using python gdata

Tags: python, django, gdata-api, gdata

```
def addEvent(calendar_service):
    event = gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry()
    event.content = atom.Content(text='Tennis with John 30.12.2009 15:00-16:00')
    event.quick_add = gdata.calendar.QuickAdd(value='true')
    new_event = calendar_service.InsertEvent(event, '/calendar/feeds/default/private/full')
```

This write to primary Calendar. How can i write/InsertEvent to my "foo" calendar?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, i found the url in *a_calendar.content.src* it show like "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/"+id+"/private/full"

```
def addEvent(calendar_service):
    event = gdata.calendar.CalendarEventEntry()
    event.content = atom.Content(text='Tennis with John 30.12.2009 15:00-16:00')
    event.quick_add = gdata.calendar.QuickAdd(value='true')
    feed = calendar_service.GetOwnCalendarsFeed()
    calurl=[a_calendar.content.src for i, a_calendar in enumerate(feed.entry)]
    new_event = calendar_service.InsertEvent(event, calurl[1]) #calurl[1] select the 2. cal of own's cals
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying a different URL for InsertEvent. See the docs on [retrieving calendars](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_python.html#RetrievingCalendars) or just try hitting the listed URL with a GET. Use a retrieved calendar's URL instead of '/calendar/feeds/default/private/full' in the InsertEvent call.

---